# What is considered as the time since PhD degree granted?

Tags: postdocs

In certain postdoc positions, the eligibility criteria says, "candidate's PhD has received their PhD within last 4 years."

So, if I defended on December 2019 and got my degree (convocation) on May 2020. Started postdoc from June 2020. So will my 4 years from now will be calculated on the basis of May 2020 or December 2019?

Comment: I think you can say you _officially_ received your PhD in May, 2020.

Comment: Have a look on your full academic transcript - it should have a date that may be the viva date or the ceremony date or some other date. Mine is the date that the university committee agreed that I should be awarded the PhD, which was a few weeks after the end of defence matters and a couple of months before I actually got the bit of paper.

Answer (score 1):

Major competitions for postdoctoral fellowships have detailed rules which answer this question, but in different ways.  Some use the date the degree was awarded.  Others use the date of the defense or viva.

If it is not specified, assume the later date is used.

Answer (score 0):

It only depends on the date on your degree, not the date you defended. So if your degree was awarded May 2020, that's the date which counts.

Comment: This is often but not always correct.

Comment: That's sometimes not even that clear. In Germany, the PhD certificate is typically back-dated to the defense date.